# Android custom Gallery Adapter problem

Tags: android, gallery

I have three galleries in a same screen. And now I have set Adapter class to these galleries with different resources. But all my galleries are being filled with the last set of input resource which I have given for my third Gallery. Here is my code,

```
    gallery_one.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,Config.Jewel_Images));
    gallery_two.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,Config.designs_Images));
    gallery_three.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,Config.recommended_Images));

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.HelloGallery);
        // mGalleryItemBackground = a.getResourceId(
        // R.styleable.HelloGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();

    }
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,Integer gallery[]) {
        mContext = c;
        mImageIds=gallery;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mImageIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
        pos = arg0;
        i.setImageResource(mImageIds[arg0]);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams((screen_width/3),(screen_height/6)));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        // i.setBackgroundResource(mGalleryItemBackground);
        return i;
    }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is, all my galleries are filled with the last value which I pass to the adapter Class.

Can anyone help me?.

Comment: comment gallery2 and gallery3 setAdapter line and check what it gives you

Comment: It shows correctly.No problem at all. Only when I set more than a adapter the problem arises

Comment: Thats because your mImageIds is global if possible post you more code where mImageIds has been declared and accessed

Comment: @Saurabh. +1 for the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mImageIds=gallery;
```

Define `mImageIds` inside the CustomAdapter... My guess is since `mImageIds` is globally Declared, its value is overwritten each time you set the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    int imageBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return pics.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
        iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,120));
        iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
        return iv;
    }

}
```